# How do I create custom GUI controls in Eclipse for use in Android app layouts?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

OK the header says it.

I want to be able to create my own controls such as buttons, textviews, edittext boxes, spinners, and so on. I can create the images in CS5 but how do I turn those images into functional GUI components? Thanks

Comment: So when I add a "TextView" control to my layout I get:

`<TextView
  android:id="@+id/TextView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:gravity="right"
  android:paddingRight="5dp"
  android:text="@string/bTotal"
  android:textColor="#000" >
</TextView>`

in the xml file. Where does the "TextView" file reside, 
and where is it's image file stored? Seems like I should be 
able to copy these files, change the image file, make a few
short edits to the xml file and have my new custom controls.
Am I off here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to create a custom looking version of those controls right?

You could make an ImageButton component for any custom button you made, and use the attribute android:src, like

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
```

Similarly for EditText you can use the attribute android:background.

Edit: 
The android controls are not stored as standard image files anywhere accessible. The standard designs that you mentioned are the default look of the elements.

To change it, you would have to create the background yourself and store it as a .png file in the drawable folder of your project. Make sure you name this file only in lower case and with no special characters like spaces etc.. Copy this file into all the drawable folders(drawable-hdpi,ldpi etc).

Then you have to refer to this file within your  box as

```
<EditText
    android:background="@drawable/your_edit_text_graphic_file_name"
    android:text="@string/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    -- all other attribute declarations --
</EditText>
```

Similarly, for other elements you would have to use android:src like is mentioned earlier to refer to your own graphic!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Karan yes! Thanks for clarifying. I want to use the controls in Eclipse but create my own image for them. If every app had the standard built in text box or slider bar then our apps would get boring really quick.

Comment: So my question now is... where are the files saved or how would I add my custom controles to the palette in Eclipse. Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, I'm just getting into Java, and Android. The last thing I coded was PLC for a machine control in 1993. OH how things change. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok I'll just make an edit to my answer to provide those details as well. And yeah I understand :D

Comment: 8 months later and I still can't 1up your answer. I didn't have a clue what you were talking about. Now, without even thinking about it, 14+ hours a day. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You just create your `CustomView` extend `View` or `TextView`.... and implement event handle. Android Developer had a training about this [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) . When you finish you can find your custom view in `GraphicLayout` => `CustomView` in `Eclipse` and add like normal components.

Images just provide nice appearance not event handle so you can not just make image to component

Comment: Thanks Yul! This does seem to be what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `CSS` in case of android you have to use `XML` file for UI designing.You can create UI in `XML` statically or dynamically(i.e. Programmatically). You can create button in android in the following manner.

```
    <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Your btn Name"/>
```

You can access this button in your java file by getting id of button and use it.

Hope this helps.
For more info read this post http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: 8 months later and I still can't 1up your answer. When you posted it though I didn't have a clue what you were talking about. Now, without even thinking about it, 14+ hours a day. :) Thanks again!